# Close the `loader` here if I need to use the Real-time feature as well as an `async` pipe on the template

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Can you tell me how to close the `loader` here if I need to use the Real-time feature as well as an `async` pipe on the template?

Since it has a real-time feature it doesn't work with `finalize` operator i.e. never completes. So any clue here, please.

*component.ts*

```
 private getAlerts(loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement): void {
    this.alertsChanged$ = this.alertsService.getAlerts().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.loadingService.dismissLoader(loader); // here is the problem
      }),
      map((res) => res)     
    );
  }
```

*service.ts*

```
 getAlerts(): Observable<AlertModel[]> {
    return this.angularFireDatabase
      .list<AlertModel>(`groups/${this.groupId}/alerts`)
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

*.html*

```
 <app-alerts
      [alerts]="alertsChanged$ | async"
  ></app-alerts>
```

Comment: How about: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap ?

Comment: @R.Richards Oh... It works. Please put it as an answer. Since I have used `finalize` everywhere I didn't think anything other than that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `finalize` doesn't work then use `tap`. See below.

```
private getAlerts(loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement): void {
    this.alertsChanged$ = this.alertsService.getAlerts().pipe(
        tap(() => {
            this.loadingService.dismissLoader(loader);
        }),
        map((res) => res)     
    );
}
```

See here for details: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap